# looped values dont work for Sendgrid substitutions but the same hardcoded ones do

Tags: php, json, curl, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to test out Sendgrid's transactional templates for work. I was able to send mail when values were hardcoded, but not when I provide them with a variable. Lets take a look:

my headers:

```
$headers = array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Authorization: Bearer my_actual_api_key',
            );
```

my $data array:

```
$resetLink = 'na';
$reset = 'Please, click here to activate your account';
$user = 'MyName';
$data = ['reset'=>$reset, 'user'=>$user, 'resetLink'=>$resetLink];
```

$subs is created by doing:

```
if($data){
        foreach($data as $k=>$v){
            $subs.= '"{{'.$k.'}}":"'.$v.'"';

            if($last_element != $v){
                $subs .=",";
            }
        }
    }
```

which outputs:

```
"{{reset}}": "Please, click here to activate your account.",
"{{user}}": "MyName",
"{{resetLink}}": "na"
```

Just what I want!

however, if I do:

```
$json = '{
            "personalizations": [{
                "to": [{
                    "email": "'.$to.'",
                    "name": "Example 01"
                }],
                "subject": "'.$subject.'",
                "substitutions": {
                    '.$subs.'
                }
            }],
            "from": {
                "email": "'.$from.'",
                "name": "'.$from.'"
            },
            "reply_to": {
                "email": "'.$from.'",
                "name": "'.$from.'"
            },

            "template_id": "My_actual_temnplate_id"


        }';
```

I get back:

```
{"errors":[{"message":"Bad Request","field":null,"help":null}]}
```

BUT, if I do:

```
$json = '{
            "personalizations": [{
                "to": [{
                    "email": "'.$to.'",
                    "name": "Example 01"
                }],
                "subject": "'.$subject.'",
                "substitutions": {
                    "{{reset}}": "Please, click here to activate your account.",
                   "{{user}}": "MyName",
                   "{{resetLink}}": "na"
                }
            }],
            "from": {
                "email": "'.$from.'",
                "name": "'.$from.'"
            },
            "reply_to": {
                "email": "'.$from.'",
                "name": "'.$from.'"
            },

            "template_id": "1959ba19-3bc7-455b-a577-7a340f4c5fd9"
        }';
```

I can cURL out and send my mail just fine, with no errors using the following.

Heres the cURL, standard stuff:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

I have also tried making this json as an array and then using json_encode(), no luck there either, same error non-message as above. This is json that was provided someplace on the Sendgrid site, just fyi.

As you can see, I have everything as string, which accounts for most of the answers I've found. Can someone shed some light on why this is happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Came in this morning and the code worked, there was no further issue with that loop generating the substitutions. The framework (Yii2) was caching. 1 refresh after a few hours was all it needed.